# How to New table create in laravel

Tags: laravel

MY commend Prompt:

```
  C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\laravel>php artisan make:migration                  
  create_datas_table

  Created Migration: 2018_02_03_095922_create_datas_table

  C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\laravel>php artisan make:model datas
  Model created successfully.

  C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\laravel>php artisan migrate --datas
  The "--datas" option does not exist.
```

How is I create new table.please explain

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#creating-tables

Answer (score 4):

You could mention the table name while making the migration file. It will add some extra code including the table name in migration file. Example

```
 php artisan make:migration create_datas_table --create=datas
```

And the model name should be the plural form the table name. It will help you reduce some more code in Model. Example:

```
php artisan make:model Data
```

If you do not follow the convention you must mention the table name inside the model like this

```
protected $table = 'different_table_name_will_here';
```

Finally, to migrate the table just run the migration command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

I think this will help.

Answer (score 0):

E.g for creating a User Model

php artisan make:model User -mcr

1.-m, --migration Create a new migration file for the user model.

2.-c, --controller Create a new controller for the user model.

3.-r, --resource Indicates if the generated controller should be a resource controller

run php artisan make:model --help you can see all the available options

Answer (score -1):

You may use

```
php artisan make:model Date -m
```